# How to get labels of subclasses of a specific class in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

[Ontology Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVW3r.png) I am new in Ontology development, I need to get labels of all subclasses of [Link to Image of Ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0cXf.png) a specific class.
            I have already tried many queries but none of them working.
            If anyone can help me Thanks.
    I have already tried the following query

```sql
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { 
?subject rdfs:subClassOf?object.
filter regex (?object ,"CSProjects","i").
}
```

Comment: You should try to select the labels in your query. How else should it work? And classes are identified by a URI, thus use the URI instead of a REGEX match.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me sample query please, i have linked my ontology code

Comment: If you make the source of your ontology available, rather than an image of it, you are more likely to get a tested query as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the labels, then you have to state that in your query.
2. Classes are identified by a URI, thus, use the URI instead of a REGEX operation:

```sql
SELECT ?cls ?clsLabel WHERE {
 ?cls rdfs:subClassOf <http://THE/URI/OF/YOUR/CLASS/CSProjects> ;
      rdfs:label ?clsLabel
}
```

Note, this will only return the explicitly asserted subclasses if no reasoning is enabled in the SPARQL engine.

Comment: 'SELECT ?cls ?clsLabel
 WHERE {
 ?cls rdfs:subClassOf 
<http://www.semanticweb.org/ghayoornaqvi/ontologies/2017/5/FYPOntology#CSProjects/>;
      rdfs:label ?clsLabel.'
}
It should be like that?

Comment: I have tried the following query, but its not returning anything.
Select ?cls ?clslabel WHERE
{ ?cls rdfs:subClassOf <URI>
rdfs:label ?clslabel
}
I am able to get all labels by simple matching,
Select ?label ?subject
{ ?label rdfs:label ?subject
filter regex(?subject ,"CS","i")
}

Comment: Don't forget the protocol of the URI, i.e. `http` probably.